# Will the United States Presidential Election (day asteroid) be back soon?

Tags: asteroids, orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics, near-earth-object, collision

My google news feed is awash with mono-themed articles, including a near Earth asteroid that passed by around election day 2020 in the US.

We can all hope that neither will lead to an extinction level event :-)

My question is about the asteroid itself.

1. Will [2018 VP1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_VP1) pass close to the Earth again this century?
2. Did it before?
3. Does this current pass have any *particularly notable or consequential* "keyhole-like" impact on its future orbit?

---

Cool GIF of several years of trajectory, about 5 MB so too large to embed directly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animation_of_2018_VP1%27s_orbit_around_Sun.gif

---

Background on Keyholes:

- [Do all dangerous asteroids first pass through keyholes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41550/12102)
- [Understanding gravitational keyhole analysis for Near-Earth Objects](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13045/12102)
- [Gravitational keyhole for spacecraft flyby?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37273/12102)

---

Comment: It would have been helpful for US voters to consider the extinction-level event they have some control over.

Comment: Pre-encounter position uncertainty was 0.01 au along track, better wait a few days for [actual observations](https://minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?object_id=K18V01P).

Comment: @RobJeffries yes, those crazy-haired "visionaries" running on platforms of restoring past glories just can't be trusted ;-) Let's hope that the US has learned its lesson again, at least for another century that appeasement of a monster doesn't work.

Comment: With an absolute magnitude of 30.9, 2018 VP1 is an extremely tiny Near Earth Object with an estimated size of 1-9 meters, depending on what you assume for the albedo. This is less than half the size of the Chelyabinsk impactor, so worst case is a large fireball in the upper atmosphere

Comment: @astrosnapper Good point! OTOH, it would do serious damage to any satellite it hit.

Comment: In which Uhoh and Rob Jeffries, though gentlemen both, low-key show themselves as Lefties. And no, I'm neither Republican or Conservative.

Comment: @RobJeffries https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-54892098 that [clever old dog](https://www.christies.com/lotfinder/Lot/robert-arneson-1930-1992-portrait-of-the-artist-5844993-details.aspx) :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfX2x.png

Comment: @uhoh The global village has found its new idiot.

Comment: @RobJeffries this turned out to be interesting! https://security.stackexchange.com/q/240677/115702